# MySql подключение по 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, localhost

Добрый день!

Установил на Mac OS X СУБД MySQL. По localhost подключается к базам данных нормально, но как сделать, чтобы подключалось и по 127.0.0.1 ?
Пользователь с таким хостом в mysql есть.

Где это можно настроить?

Comment: а в какой ip-адрес резолвится у вас имя `localhost`? проверить можно с помощью программы `host` (если присутствует): `host localhost` или, на худой конец, с помощью `ping localhost` — там может присутствовать и ip-адрес.

Comment: localhost по пингу равен 127.0.0.1. Но я не могу по ИП подключиться к базам данных, только через localhost

Comment: 1. честно говоря, абсолютно непонятно, зачем вам нужно «так, а не эдак». 2. напишите, пожалуйста, в вопросе, что именно вы делаете, что получается, что не получается, чего ожидаете, какие ошибки получаете.

Answer (score 2):

Есть два способа соединения с MySQL-сервером: через сокет и через сеть. Когда в качестве хоста вы пишите localhost - соединение по умолчанию идет через сокет, когда пишите IP-адрес - через сеть. Поэтому решения тоже два.

### Включить прием соединений через сеть

Для того, чтобы установить сетевое соединение с MySQL-сервером, следует убедиться, что оно включено. Для этого следует обнаружить конфигурационный файл my.cnf (в Windows my.ini) и в секции [mysqld] необходимо раскомментировать или создать следующие директивы

```
[mysqld]
...
# Включаем сетевое соединение
skip-networking
# Разрешаем соединение только для локального хоста
bind-address                   = 127.0.0.1
```

После перезагрузки сервера у вас включится режим сетевого взаимодействия и вы сможете обращаться через 127.0.0.1, а не через localhost.

### Явно указать сокет при установке соединения

Или, если вы хотите продолжить взаимодействие через сокет, при указании в качестве хоста 127.0.0.1 необходимо дополнительно передать параметр `--socket` в котором передать путь к файлу сокета (его можно уточнить в my.cnf)

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с подобной проблемой, решилось правкой файла php.ini, в нем  необходимо задать параметр mysql.default_socket
https://digital-planet.info/viewtopic.php?f=84&p=1473

Comment: А почему вы решили, что автор использует php?